# Share image and link from assets on Facebook

Tags: android, android-facebook, android-sharing

This is the code i'm using to share image along with clickable link.

```
ShareLinkContent shareLinkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Your Title")
                .setContentDescription("Your Description")
                .setContentUrl("http://google.com")
                .setImageUrl(getUriToDrawable())  
                .build();
```

When i remove the setImageUrl, it works properly but otherwise nothing happens. Desired behaviour is that an image should be displayed in the share content. And when you tap on that share content anywhere, it takes me to content url.

Comment: no. setting image url to an actual url fixed the case but it doesn't seem to work with uri.

Comment: check my answer below.. you can try SharePhoto option to acheive what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try share Photo option in Facebook SDK.

```
share_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sharePhotoFB("Pass your Bitmap from Drawable here");
            }
        });



void sharePhotoFB(Bitmap bmp) {
    // New FB implementation
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(context);
    ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(context);
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setCaption("My Photo").setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"))
            .setBitmap(bmp).build();

    List<SharePhoto> fbPhotos = new ArrayList<>();
    fbPhotos.add(photo);

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhotos(fbPhotos)
            .build();
    shareDialog.show(content);
  }
```

Try this if it works for you, and let me know